# In Postgres pg_stat_statements huge difference between max and mean time

Tags: postgresql, pg-stat-statements

In Postgres 14 in `pg_stat_statements`, why is there a huge time difference between `max_exec_time` and `mean_exec_time`?

Could you please help?

[image: Output of pg_stat_statements]

Answer (score 1):

That means that the execution time varies considerably. To see if that is just a single outlier or a regular occurrence, see if `stddev_exec_time` is high or not.

It can mean several things:

- Perhaps execution sometimes took long because the statement was stuck behind a lock. If that is a rare occurrence, it may me the odd `ALTER TABLE` statement.
- Perhaps the execution time varies depending on a query parameter. It may be fast for rare values and slow for frequent ones. Test with different parameters!
- Perhaps execution time varies depending on how much of the data happens to be cached in RAM. Look at a high "buffers" footprint in the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output.